# adjacent states webservice

Tags: api, gis

Has anybody heard about a webservice or anything of that kind which provides adjacent states in US? defining an enum for over 50 states is not fun and I do really appreciate all suggestions
 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, this is what collected myself... may be it saves someone a few hours (used http://adjacentstates.com/ as reference)

```
   def states = [
        "Alabama":["Florida","Georgia","Mississippi","Tennessee"],
        "Alaska":[],
        "Arizona":["California","Colorado","Nevada","New Mexico","Utah"],
        "Arkansas":["Louisiana","Mississippi","Missouri","Oklahoma","Tennessee","Texas"],
        "California":["Oregon", "Nevada","Arizona"],
        "Colorado":["Arizona","Kansas","Oklahoma","Nebraska","New Mexico","Utah","Wyoming"],
        "Connecticut":["Massachussetts","New York","Rhode Island"],
        "Delaware":["Maryland", "New Jersey", "Pennsylvania"],
        "District of Columbia":["Maryland", "Virginia"],
        "Florida":["Alabama","Georgia"],
        "Georgia":["Alabama","Florida","North Carolina","South Carolina","Tennessee"],
        "Hawaii":[],
        "Idaho":["Montana","Nevada","Oregon","Utah","Washington","Wyoming"],
        "Illinois":["Indiana","Iowa","Kentucky","Missouri","Wisconsin"],
        "Indiana":["Illinois","Kentucky","Michigan","Ohio"],
        "Iowa":["Illinois", "Kansas", "Minnesota", "Missouri", "Nebraska", "South Dakota", "Wisconsin"],
        "Kansas":["Colorado", "Missouri","Nebraska","Oklahoma"],
        "Kentucky":["Illinois", "Illinois", "Missouri", "North Carolina","Ohio", "Tennessee", "Virginia", "West Virginia"],
        "Louisiana":["Arkansas", "Mississippi", "Texas"],
        "Maine":["New Hampshire"],
        "Maryland":["Delaware","Pennsylvania","Virginia","West Virgina"],
        "Massachusetts":["Connecticut","New Hampshire","New York","Rhode Island","Vermont"],
        "Michigan":["Indiana","Ohio","Wisconsin"],
        "Minnesota":["Iowa", "North Dakota", "South Dakota", "Wisconsin"],
        "Mississippi":["Alabama", "Arkansas", "Louisiana", "Tennessee"],
        "Missouri":["Arkansas","Illinois", "Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Nebraska","Oklahoma","Tennessee"],
        "Montana":["Idaho", "North Dakota", "South Dakota", "Wyoming"],
        "Nebraska":["Colorado", "Iowa", "Kansas", "South Dakota","Wyoming"],
        "Nevada":["Arizona", "California", "Idaho", "Oregon", "Utah"],
        "New Hampshire":["Maine", "Massachussetts", "Vermont"],
        "New Jersey":["Connecticut", "Delaware", "New York", "Pennsylvania"],
        "New Mexico":["Arizona", "Colorado", "Kansas", "Oklahoma", "Texas", "Utah"],
        "New York":["Connecticut", "Massachussetts", "Pennsylvania", "Vermont"],
        "North Carolina":["South Carolina","Tennessee", "Virginia"],
        "North Dakota":["Minnesota", "Montana", "South Dakota"],
        "Ohio":["Indiana", "Kentucky", "Michigan", "Pennsylvania", "West Virgina"],
        "Oklahoma":["Arkansas", "Colorado", "Kansas", "Montana", "New Mexico", "Texas"],
        "Oregon":["California", "Idaho", "Nevada", "Washington"],
        "Pennsylvania":["Delaware", "Maryland", "New Jersey", "New York", "Ohio", "West Virgina"],
        "Rhode Island":["Connecticut", "Massachusetts"],
        "South Carolina":["Georgia", "North Carolina", "Tennessee"],
        "South Dakota":["Iowa","Minnesota", "Montana", "Nebraska", "North Dakota", "Wyoming"],
        "Tennessee":["Alabama", "Arkansas", "Georgia", "Kentucky", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "North Carolina", "Virginia"],
        "Texas":["Arkansas", "Louisiana", "New Mexico", "Oklahoma"],
        "Utah":["Arizona", "Colorado", "Idaho", "Nevada", "New Mexico", "Wyoming"],
        "Vermont":["Massachussetts", "New Hampshire", "New York"],
        "Virginia":["Delaware", "Kentucky", "Maryland", "North Carolina", "Pennsylvania", "Tennessee", "West Virgina"],
        "Washington":["Idaho", "Oregon"],
        "West Virginia":["Kentucky", "Pennsylvania", "Ohio", "Virginia"],
        "Wisconsin":["Illinois", "Iowa", "Michigan", "Minnesota"],
        "Wyoming":["Colorado", "Idaho", "Montana", "South Dakota", "Utah"]
       ]
```